# In S02, why does Mr Sutherland/Donald Hoffman work for Joanna?

Tags: mr-robot

Tyrell is missing and Joanna seems to be having financial difficulties (she tries but is unable to get Tyrell's severance package).

So why is Sutherland still loyally working for Joanna (including murdering someone for her)?